# What does a dot over $\dot{D}^2$ mean in topology?

Tags: notation, geometric-topology, knot-theory

Reading http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214437136, I don't want to guess at the meaning of the overdot on page 1 $$\dot{H} = ( D^2 \times \dot{D}^2, \partial D^2 \times \dot{D}^2)$$.

---

J. Differential Geom.
Volume 17, Number 3 (1982), 357-453.
The topology of four-dimensional manifolds

Michael Hartley Freedman

Comment: The symbol is most probably $\circ$, not $\cdot$, and it might stand for "the interior of". (I did not open your link.)

Comment: It does look like a dot rather than a circle. It should be mentioned that it is differential topological context, rather than general topological.

Comment: A google search for ""open 2-handle" topology" yields a [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=WBdFf7djBDoC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=%22open+2-handle%22+topology&source=bl&ots=1Oe1zdg5e7&sig=oDlbQiLxbioEyO9rN7utLGlRis4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBuZL40_LTAhUB5CYKHfuSByMQ6AEILzAE#v=onepage&q=%22open%202-handle%22%20topology&f=false) to a book, in which such a thing is written as $B_i^2 \times \mathrm{int}D^2$. So even though it is definitely typeset in the link with an overset $\cdot$ rather than $\circ$, the interpretation given by @Did is likely correct.

Comment: Did's interpretation (but not symbol) is indeed correct. Freedman will continue using similar notation. Good luck with the paper.